# HTML & JS Error not showing (Checkbox error showing in checkbox)

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am making a food delivery service for practice and I am requiring the user to select at least one food. The error message is showing in the checkbox:

[image]

I would like the error message here:

[image]

**The error is working properly, but it is just in the wrong place.

This is the HTML

```
            <h2 class="mg-b-15">Type of drinks:</h2><br>
            <input id="checkboxFT" type="checkbox" value="Pepsi" name="type" class="mg-b-15"><span
                class="tx-20">Pepsi</span><br>
            <input id="checkboxPT" type="checkbox" value="Sprite" name="type" class="mg-b-15"><span
                class="tx-20">Sprite</span><br>
            <input id="checkboxI" type="checkbox" value="Apple Juice" name="type" class="mg-b-15"><span
                class="tx-20">Apple Juice</span><br>
            <input id="checkboxII" type="checkbox" value="Orange Juice" name="type" class="mg-b-15"><span
                class="tx-20">Orange Juice</span><br>
            <input id="checkboxIII" type="checkbox" value="Fruit Punch" name="type" class="mg-b-15"><span
                class="tx-20">Fruit Punch</span><br>
```

This is the JS

```
        type:       {
            required: true,
            minlength: 1
        },
    },
```

The error message

```
        type: { // makes user choose drink
            required: 'Please choose a drink'
        },
```

Validation

```
 $("#personalAndFoodFormId").validate({ // Make sure the user enters the required data
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
        type:       {
            required: true,
            minlength: 1
        },
    },
```

Comment: check the edit please.

Comment: Hi. You didn't say where you want to display the error.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I would like it on the right of "drink type", check edit please

Comment: You probably need to post more of your codes for us to help. It looks like you might be using jquery-validate?